# How to enable email to customer with LicenseCloud

Tags: licensecloud-api

How do you enable sending license key by email when using the Custom IPNs?

When i setup paypal IPN it says it will send an email with the license key. but then it says No under the Email Cust. column. I did a test purchase to see if it would send an email and it did NOT send anything.

How do I enable this and is the email editable?

Answer (score 0):

Just found this question after asking how to get email working. Never got email working but did find a solution if willing to use a third party service:

[Licensecloud Auto Email of Key Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52023277/licensecloud-auto-email-of-key-not-working/52028991)